# Is there a way to change the default login/password prompts?

Tags: login, password

Just noticed something odd happened to two of my Linux servers. We have two dozen Ubuntu 18.04 LTS servers, and all of them ask us for a prompt in the same way:

```
# ssh admin@pl3poland
admin@pl3poland's password:
```

However, we recently started enforcing stronger password requirements on two servers. We changed the settings in /etc/pam.d/common-password for libpwquality.

Before:

```
password        requisite                       pam_pwquality.so retry=3
```

After:

```
password        requisite                       pam_pwquality.so retry=3 minlen=12 difok=3 minclass=4 maxrepeat=2 dictcheck=1 usercheck=1
```

It seems that after these values were changed, now the password prompt shows up differently. This is what comes up now:

```
# spawn ssh admin@spain
Password:
```

This is a relatively minor difference, but it has affected a few of our automated routines where we use expect scripts to connect to systems. I've changed the script to look for "sword:" instead of the full "password:", but I'm just curious why that would change, and if there is any way to change it back?

Looking through documentation, I found a command called "password-prompt" but it does not look like that is something I can use to permanently set the password prefix.

Anyone able to direct me to a .conf file or some documentation that explains how to change this? I come from an AIX background, and there was a file called /etc/security/login.cfg that we could change to adjust the "herald" for each login. But I don't see something similar in Ubuntu.

Thx

Steve N.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- `user@server's password` is used for password authentication
- `Password:` is used for keyboard-interactive authentication

Both are set with an SSH option:

- `PreferredAuthentications=password`
- `PreferredAuthentications=keyboard-interactiv`

as definied in [rfc 4252](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4252) and [rfc 4256](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4256) so it is unlikely related to a change in `/etc/pam.d/common-password` and more to do with a change in `.ssh/config` and the setting `PreferredAuthentications` or by setting it with an option with `ssh -o`.

Comment: We don't have a setting for PreferredAuthentications in our ~/.ssh or in the /etc/ssh directory. But it does give me something to look at. I can try ssh with debugging to see if it is stopping at the same authentication method. And if not, why.

Comment: @S.Nixon did you find out what it was for you? :)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem was exactly what Rinzwind had indicated. Using the ssh -vv debugger flag, I was able to see that Ubuntu Server #1 (polaris) was stopping at the "password" authentication method, while Ubuntu Server #2 (spain) was

To demonstrate, here is the tail end of the debugger login session:

```
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /.ssh/id_rsa
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Trying private key: /.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: Next authentication method: password
admin@polaris's password:
```

Versus the one on my spain server:

```
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /.ssh/id_rsa
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Trying private key: /.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: Next authentication method: keyboard-interactive
debug2: userauth_kbdint
debug2: we sent a keyboard-interactive packet, wait for reply
debug2: input_userauth_info_req
debug2: input_userauth_info_req: num_prompts 1
Password:
```

Now for my own curiosity, I should really spend the time to find out why one is using password while the other is at keyboard-interactive. I suspect it is an issue with the id_rsa.pub or authorized_keys entries. But I have not had the time to research it further.

The solution we came up with to fix our expect scripts is to simply look for "assword:" instead of "password:" that was used previously. That way, if we run into the issue again, the automated routines will continue regardless if we get "Password:" or "password:" as part of the login string.